# Android Move to previous fragment without reload

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `HomeFragment` and `LoginFragment` in the same `Activity`. At first it shows the `HomeFragment` and then go to `LoginFragment`. But when I back to `HomeFragment` it reloads the `HomeFragment`.

How to make the `HomeFragment` not reload when I press back from `LoginFragment`.

Thanks in advance. Here is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void setEvent() {
    img_action_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeKeyboard(getApplication(), img_action_back.getWindowToken());
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment instanceof LoginFragment)
        {
            LoginFragment loginFragment = (LoginFragment)fragment;
            if(loginFragment.fromDrawer)
                Navigator.showHomeFragment(mContext);
            else
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Navigator.java**

```
public static void showHomeFragment(Context context) {
   final FragmentTransaction transaction =
   getFragmentManager(context).beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(CONTAINER_ID, new HomeFragment());
   transaction.commit();
}

public static void showLoginFragment(Context context,Boolean fromDrawer,String infoRegister) {
   final FragmentTransaction transaction =
   getFragmentManager(context).beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(CONTAINER_ID,
   LoginFragment.newInstance(fromDrawer,infoRegister),"login");
   transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the reloading anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're recreating a new `HomeFragment` instance when you press back. You should instead pop the `FragmentManager` backstack.

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     if (fragment instanceof LoginFragment) {
        LoginFragment loginFragment = (LoginFragment)fragment;
        if(loginFragment.fromDrawer) {
            getFragmentManager(mContext).popBackStack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure you add the `LoginFragment` to the backstack.

```
public static void showLoginFragment(Context context,Boolean fromDrawer,String infoRegister)
{
   final FragmentTransaction transaction =
   getFragmentManager(context).beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(CONTAINER_ID,
   LoginFragment.newInstance(fromDrawer,infoRegister),"login");
   transaction.addToBackStack(null);
   transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@SunnySydeUp has a nice answer. I've found some improvement scope in your code.

You need to add the `Fragment` in the back stack so that the `super.onBackPressed` call won't recreate the `Fragment` again like the other answer says.

But as you're really worried about recreating `Fragment` you might initialize them once and use the instance again during transaction.

So in the `onCreate` function of your `Activity` initialize both of them first like this.

```
private HomeFragment mHomeFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
}
```

Now your `onBackPressed` may look like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment instanceof LoginFragment) {
       if(loginFragment.fromDrawer) {
           super.onBackPressed();
       } else {
          finish();
       }
   }
}
```

And the `Navigator.java`

```
public static void showHomeFragment(Context context) {
   final FragmentTransaction transaction =
   getFragmentManager(context).beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(CONTAINER_ID, mHomeFragment);
   transaction.commit();
}

public static void showLoginFragment(Context context,Boolean fromDrawer,String infoRegister) {
   final FragmentTransaction transaction =
   getFragmentManager(context).beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(CONTAINER_ID,
   LoginFragment.newInstance(fromDrawer,infoRegister),"login");

   transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```